# Checking for blank string in array

Tags: c

I have an array which is of type **char which contains various values. I need to check whether the string is empty or NULL but no matter what I try it doesn't.

Below is the code I am currently using.

```
if (!strcmp(reportParameterArray[P_CALLINGPARTY], ""))
    {
        printf("****PERFORMING REPORT WITH RESTRICTIONS*****\n");
        exit (0);
    }
```

P_CALLINGPARTY is an ENUM value which is used to determine from what index within the array the value should be retrieve. I have tried using the above code as well as `reportParameterArray[P_CALLINGPARTY] == NULL`, `reportParameterArray[P_CALLINGPARTY] == ""` and `reportParameterArray[P_CALLINGPARTY] = "\0"` neither of which work. It is always going into the if statement.

When I debug the code and print the value within gdb I get the following output.

```
print reportParameterArray[10]
$5 = 0x8062550 ""
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: did you try `print reportParameterArray[P_CALLINGPARTY]`in gdb?

Comment: @DarenThomas That was the last section of the question with the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the first *character* is the string terminator:

```
if (reportParameterArray[P_CALLINGPARTY][0] == '\0')
{
    /* ... */
}
```

You can't use the equality operator `==` to compare strings, as it will only compare the *pointer* and not the string, and comparing to a literal string pointer will always be false.

Comment: Thanks this worked, I will accept the answer but SO is making me wait 11 minutes

Comment: This will fail miserably if one of the pointers in the array is NULL.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Of course, that's so obvious that I didn't even think about pointing it out. Also, I _assume_ (yes, bad and all that) that the OP already have checked that, as otherwise the OPs code would already crash horribly.

Comment: I am a beginner at C but I have already first checked that its not null

Answer (score 2):

If you have an array of strings (i.e., character pointers), and you want to test that one of its members is "empty", you really should check for both of two conditions: either that the array element is NULL, or that it is not null but 0 length.  The safest way to do that is this:

```
char *array[];
. . .
if (NULL == array[i] || '\0' == *array[i]) {
    <it's empty>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is perfectly fine, it's just the actual string comparison which is wrong.

Strings in C are character arrays, or in your case, `char*`s, which are pointers to the first element in the string. This can work this way because a standard array can decay to a pointer to the first element in that array.

Anyway, assume I have two strings, "foo" and "bar", both stored in a char* like follows:

```
char* str1 = "foo";
char* str2 = "bar";
```

`str1` and `str2` will be pointers to the first character in each string, which is a *memory address*. `str1` might point to 0x10, and `str2` to 0x20, for example.

Now let's assign "foo" to `str2` using `str2 = "foo";`. This will actually change the memory address `str2` points to, since it's a new string, so let's assume this is 0x30 for now.

Now, given `str1 == 0x10` and `str2 == 0x30`, and there's a string "foo" located at each, what happens if we run `str1 == str2`? Despite them containing the same string, they the equality check doesn't work since they're at different addresses, and we're comparing the pointers.

Instead, there's a function `strcmp` which does the comparison, and returns 0 if they match, so `strcmp(str1, str2) == 0`.

**tl;dr** use `strcmp` instead.